# Schedule a recurring SQL job using an IDE

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

I would like to run a basic query at 8am everyday, preferably using the Jetbrains Datagrip IDE.

The query is irrelevant, but here it is for illustrative purposes:

```
select month,count(*) as distinct_month
into table.table
from table2.table
```

What are the steps required to schedule this job.  For what it's worth, I'm query against an AWS Redshift database.  Thank you.

Comment: Postgres does not have a built-in scheduler. Don't know about Redshift

Comment: Is there any work around?  How do people who use postgres schedule recurring jobs?  Do people abandon postgres all together if they cannot schedule jobs?

Comment: They simply use `cron` or other operating system schedulers. There are some extensions available that provide built-in schedulers but I doubt any of them would run with redshift as that is built on a really, really old version of Postgres

Comment: You can also schedule this query using AWS Lambda with scheduled events: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html